# how to read credit card info using IDTECH card swiper in IOS?

Tags: ios, credit-card, authorize.net

i want to read credit card information with IDTECH card swiper using Authorized.net iOS SDKs. i connect IDTECH swiper with my IOS Device and swipe credit card but i cant get card data .

Can anyone have more information about any IOS SDKs for get card data using swiper or any objective-C default class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SDK of manufacture itself. Because every manufacture has its own mechanism to read data from card reader.

You may download [IDTECH SDK](http://www.idtechproducts.com/support/daq/unimag.html#Q24) here.

For  more help, you may visit [IDTECH FAQs](http://www.idtechproducts.com/support/daq/unimag.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer,Rahul Patel. but is it not possible to use IDTECH swiper with Authorized.net sdk? they given list of the swiper device and IDTECH is one of them.

Comment: @user2236407 I am not sure about it. You may ask to their support team and can confirm it.

Comment: is it possible to use Authorized.net sdk and IDTECH swiper only for get CreditCard data like number,mon,year,etc. i dont want to use full payment on authorized.net. only read data from card.

Comment: As @RahulPatel mentioned, you'll need to use BOTH SDKs: the manufactuer SDK to read the hardware device, Authorize.Net to send transactions to the gateway.